# Can I execute a task after the build and before the debugging of my code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code.

This is my `tasks.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "/Project/Admin/Api.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
```

The point is that when I hit <kbd>F5</kbd> I get **Access Denied** error to my logs directory inside the `bin` directory.

Since I can't debug as root, I want to run `chmod -R 777 /path_to_bin` before debugging and after each build.

Can I do that?

Comment: are you using Linux OS?

Comment: use a `compound` task as a `prebuildTask`